# Javascript Regular Expression for facebook-like profile badge

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a regex to create a string of characters with the following criteria:

- Can be variable length (max 30 characters)
- Can have only alphanumeric (a-z,A-Z) and Numeric characters(0-9)
- Can have only these special characters "-","." anywhere in the string
- Must start with only alphanumeric or numeric, not special characters
- Must be at least 5 characters

The "badge" string will need to be used in the url of the site, any advice on whether this string would be alright would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Oh, and the minimum is 5 characters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegExp's do not create strings they are used to validate or match them. Is that what you mean?

A RegExp to validate a string against your constraints would be

```
  /^[a-z0-9][-,\.a-z0-9]{4,29}$/i
```

Explanation :

```
   /^                  Start of string
   [a-z0-9]            One character in the set a-z or 0-9 
                       (A-Z also valid since we specify flag i at the end
   [-,\.a-z0-9]{4,29}  A sequence of at least 4 and no more than 29 characters
                       in the set. Note . is escaped since it has special meaning
   $                   End of string (ensures there is nothing else
   /i                  All matches are case insensitive a-z === A-Z
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, yes I meant I have a javascript variable taken from an input, and want to validate it. Testing now...

Comment: +1 I think this is the only answer which is actually correct - me and da_b0uncer both allow underscores erroneously.

Answer (score 0):

`^\w[\w-,\.]{4}[\w-,\.]{0,25}$`

This translates to:

> Match a string starting with an alphanumeric, then 4 valid characters,
>   then up to 25 more valid characters. Valid is alphanumeric "," "-" or
>   "."

The following PowerShell script gives unit-tests for this rule.

```
$test = "^\w[\w-,\.]{4}[\w-,\.]{0,25}$"

# Test length rules.
PS > "abcd" -match $test # False: Too short (4 chars)
False
PS > "abcde" -match $test # True: 5 chars
True
PS > "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd" -match $test # True: 30 chars
True
PS > "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcde" -match $test # False: Too long
False

# Test character validity rules.
PS > "abcd,-." -match $test # True: Contains only valid chars
True
PS > "abcd+" -match $test # False: Contains invalid chars
False

# Test start rules.
PS > "1bcde" -match $test # True: Starts with a number
True
PS > ".abcd" -match $test # False: Starts with invalid character
False
PS > ",abcd" -match $test # False: Starts with invalid character
False
PS > "-abcd" -match $test # False: Starts with invalid character
False
```

Comment: Just realised mine is not quite right. `\w` allows underscores.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick response. I will test each answer and report back, as they all seem different. RegEx's are really not my strong point, wish I could understand them more!

Answer (score 0):

```
^([\d\w][\d\w.-]{4,29})$
```

Made with: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/